# É possível diminuir a velocidade do scroll a partir de determinada seção da página?

Tags: jquery

Estou com um projeto de página única, onde ao descer o scroll, fará uma animação de broca perfurando as camadas da terra, até que no fim, ao perfurar a água, a tela automaticamente role para o topo. Acontece, que ao chegar na parte de água, quero diminuir a velocidade da rolagem, pois está me incomodando a forma como acontece.

HTML

```
<header id="topo">
</header>
<div id="content">
    <div id="broca">
    </div>
</div>
<footer id="water">    
</footer>
```

CSS

```
header, footer{
display:block;
height:700px;
background:red;
width:100%;
}
#content{
display:block;
width:100%;
height:1500px;
background:blue;
}
#broca{
width:50px;
height:0;
background:#000;
max-height:1500px;
}
```

JQuery

```
var counter = 0;
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var $broca = $('#broca');
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (st > $broca.height()){
            $broca.clearQueue().animate({
                height: st } , 500);
        }


$(window).scroll(function() {
       if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
               if (counter == 0){
                   counter++;
               $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1500);
        }
    }
});

        if( st == 0 ) {

        } else {
            $broca.show();
        }
    }).scroll();
})
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9nzmdsm1/17/)

Comment: cara, eu acho que os usuário do site não vão gostar desse scroll automático de volta para o topo... se fosse você deixava só a broca animada e independente do scroll, descendo e subindo sozinha em um loop infinito.

Comment: Obrigado por responder Jader. Concordo totalmente com você, detestei essa ideia. Sugeri também essa alternativa que você falou, porém fui voto vencido aqui na empresa.

Answer (score 2):

Altere a velocidade da animação para demorar mais tempo executar. Se não estou em erro o `animate` do JQuery tem uma propriedade que define a duração em milisegundos da animação. Já estás a passar a duração:

`$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1500);`

Agora basta aumentar:

`$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 5000);`

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Joel.
Você está correto, e estou usando 5000 no site originalmente.
Sua resposta até me deu a ideia de acrescentar um 'easeInOutExpo' para modificar a forma com que sobe.